# MS Access Using Counts and Sum in Two Tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables, one which holds info about the teams, named TEAMS which looks like this:

```
TEAMS

Name|City|Attendance

Jets   NY  50
```

Etc.

And the other which holds info about the games played, named GAMES:

```
GAMES

Home|Visitors|Date|Result

Jets  Broncos  1/1/2012  Tie
```

Etc.

I am trying to set up a query that prints the day of the month listed in the GAMES table, followed by the amount of games on that day and then the total attendance of the games played on that day.

Right now I am able to create the query that prints out the day of the month and games played that day but when I try to add the column with attendance for that day it doesn't come out correctly at all. Here is my current query:

```
SELECT Day(Date) AS [Day of Week], Count(Day(Date)) AS [Games on Day]
FROM GAMES
GROUP BY Day(Date);
```

If i simply add `Sum(Attendance)` to the `SELECT` and then `TEAMS` to `FROM`, the attendance numbers come out with what looks to be the total of the attendance column in `TEAMS` times the number of games played on that day. Any help on how to approach this would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the attendance be an attribute of the GAME rather than the attribute of a TEAM?

Comment: The columns aren't changeable, they are set by the professor, I don't disagree with you though.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `Inner JOIN` between GAMES and TEAM since your attendance is a part of the TEAM.

```
SELECT Day(G.Date) AS [Day of Week], Count(Day(G.Date)) AS [Games on Day], Sum(Attendance)
FROM GAMES G
INNER JOIN TEAM T
On G.HOME = T.NAME
GROUP BY Day(Date)
```

Also, if you're grouping by `DAY(Date)`, you are just getting day of month back (so for Aug 12, 2014, you just get `12`).  What happens when there are games on Aug 12 2014 and on Jan 12 2015 in the same season?  You will get a total of games played over both of those dates.  Double check to make sure that this is what you really want.

Also, attendance to a game can vary game by game.  For example, with inclement weather predicted, you may not have a sold-out crowd.  I think you should move your `Attendance` column to `GAME`.

**EDIT**

To answer the question in the comments

```
SELECT Count(Day(G.Date)) AS [Games on Day], Sum(Attendance)
FROM GAMES G
INNER JOIN TEAM T
    On G.HOME = T.NAME
WHERE G.DATE Between '01/01/2010' and '12/31/2010'
GROUP BY Day(Date)
```

Comment: thanks raj, that works. I am new to sql and thus not great with all the commands yet and forgot about join. the variables such as weather are realistic in life but this is just a simple database, thanks.

Comment: So i now understand how to do it for single date entities, however if I wanted to do the same query but now check for Games Played and Attendance in a specific month and year how would I do that? Example: find games played and attendance for January 2010 to December 2010. Should I be using a view?